# getting undefined while iterating json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON element.
I need to get the volume of every transaction type . When I try

```
var data = '{"2015:ATM01": {"volume": "2620000","count": "78"},"2015:PIN_PURCHASE01": {"volume": "5162305","count": "101"},"ALL:PIN_PURCHASE01": {"volume": "5162305","count": "101"},"ALL:DIRECT_DEPOSIT01": {"volume": "32752700","count": "50" }}';
    var JSONArray=JSON.parse(data);
    for(var k in JSONArray){
        console.log("key is  is.... "+k);
        console.log("voulume is.... "+k.volume);
    }
```

I get volume as undefined . Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qgvs9o9/

You need to retrieve volume like this :

```
JSONArray[k].volume
```

Answer (score 0):

`k` is a key(string), not an object. In order to get the object you want you need to get the value from `JSONArray` like so:

```
var data = '{"2015:ATM01": {"volume": "2620000","count": "78"},"2015:PIN_PURCHASE01": {"volume": "5162305","count": "101"},"ALL:PIN_PURCHASE01": {"volume": "5162305","count": "101"},"ALL:DIRECT_DEPOSIT01": {"volume": "32752700","count": "50" }}';
var JSONArray=JSON.parse(data);
for(var k in JSONArray){
    console.log("key is  is.... "+k);
    console.log("voulume is.... "+JSONArray[k].volume);
}
```